# Ping to azure shared folder failed -- Status: TimedOut

Tags: powershell

I am still new to Azure platform and trying to upload files to Azure shared folder using the following script:

```
  Test-NetConnection -ComputerName name.file.core.windows.net -Port 500
    # Save the password so the drive will persist on reboot
    Invoke-Expression -Command "cmdkey /add:name.file.core.windows.net  /user:Azure\user1 /pass:1234=="
    # Mount the drive
    New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\name.file.core.windows.net\folder1"


    $Destination = "\\name.file.core.windows.net \folder1\" 

    $Source = "C:\backups\"

    Get-Childitem $source *.bak -Recurse | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |Select-Object -First 1 | where {$_.fullname -like "*DB*"} | Copy-Item -destination $Destination
```

Running these commands from my local machine at the head office works fine. However if running the same commands from a remote office, its failing with the following warning messages:

```
  PS C:\Scripts> Test-NetConnection -ComputerName name.file.core.windows.net -Port 500
    WARNING: Ping to name.file.core.windows.net failed -- Status: TimedOut
    WARNING: TCP connect to name.file.core.windows.net:500 failed

New-PSDrive : The specified drive root "\\name.file.core.windows.net\folder1" either does not exist, or it is not a folder
```

Is there anything am missing here? I have looked at many online resources but could not find help

Comment: A wild guess: firewall. Check if there's a limit for allowed IP ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding Test-NetConnection, please try with port 445. If you are unable to connect, then check your network and system firewall.